# Will chaining jquery add class method trigger multiple reflows?

Tags: jquery, css, optimization, reflow

I would like to know if chaining jquery functions trigger multiple reflows or does the reflow happen only once after the end of the statement.

```
$('label[hierarchyName="' + toolbarStatus.Years[i] + '"]').addClass('active').addClass('btn-success');
```

Any input appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not a reflow expert. I will just note, though, that you can do `.addClass('active btn-success')` to add both classes at the same time.

Comment: I think reflows happen on every function in chain since they execute in order in which they are chained. Try `.addClass('active btn-success');`

Comment: yes, you can access all of those elements by chaining in your case, you can find the answer by yourself by making a simple test...

Comment: Thank You T.J. for your reply. I am still wondering if multiple reflows will be triggered.

Comment: I think it may depend on the browser.. because the browser may delay the reflow for a few milliseconds for performance optimizations in that case it might cause only a single reflow..

Comment: see `Browsers are smart` in http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It triggers multiple reflows. Chaining is just like applying multiple methods on single selector. Everytime you add a class, it regenerates the DOM and renders it..

Example is given here on JSFiddle. - http://jsfiddle.net/5kkCh/

It's just like

```
var obj = {
    first: function() { alert('first'); return obj; },
    second: function() { alert('second'); return obj; },
    third: function() { alert('third'); return obj; }
}

obj.first().second().third();
```

Here's jQuery's addClass function

```
addClass: function( value ) {
    var classes, elem, cur, clazz, j, finalValue,
        i = 0,
        len = this.length,
        proceed = typeof value === "string" && value;

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        return this.each(function( j ) {
            jQuery( this ).addClass( value.call( this, j, this.className ) );
        });
    }

    if ( proceed ) {
        // The disjunction here is for better compressibility (see removeClass)
        classes = ( value || "" ).match( rnotwhite ) || [];

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            elem = this[ i ];
            cur = elem.nodeType === 1 && ( elem.className ?
                ( " " + elem.className + " " ).replace( rclass, " " ) :
                " "
            );

            if ( cur ) {
                j = 0;
                while ( (clazz = classes[j++]) ) {
                    if ( cur.indexOf( " " + clazz + " " ) < 0 ) {
                        cur += clazz + " ";
                    }
                }

                // only assign if different to avoid unneeded rendering.
                finalValue = jQuery.trim( cur );
                if ( elem.className !== finalValue ) {
                    elem.className = finalValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

If you see the for loop, it updates the class name (appends to existing class) every time addClass is called...

If you refer to article written by stubbornella (http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) changing className can cause reflows..

I hope that explains :-)

Comment: @Pazza22 & Rahul: Just because the functions run serially, that doesn't mean the browser necessarily does the reflow immediately when the class is added.

Comment: I agree. But I was just talking about how jQuery Chaining works. :-)

Comment: @RahulPatil: Well, the question is about reflows. Answering about chaining doesn't answer the question about reflows (Pazza's comment above notwithstanding). Again: I would *not* assume that the reflow happens immediately when the class is added. That would not be a very optimized implementation, and modern browsers are very optimized.

Comment: @T.J I basically assumed reflow would be occur multiple times as the code in the question is not exactly one statement(as demonstrated by Rahul). But after going through some of the comments, I am of the impression that it is browser dependent and may occur only one time. However, I will be combining the two .addClass() just to be on the safer side. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and @ Pazza22.. I have added brief explanation in an answer above, I hope that explains :D

Comment: Well, browsers are smart enough to capture minor reflows and it does not affect the performance, but in reality if you talk about HTML standalone (not considering browser's role), yes it reflows. :-)

Comment: *"... in reality if you talk about HTML standalone (not considering browser's role)..."* Without a browser, there **is** no concept of reflow. HTML is just a markup "language." There's no presentation without something to do the presentation. It's at the presentation level you have the concept of flow/reflow.

Comment: Crap, I missed "modern" browsers word. I wanted to say, it reflows on older browsers.. You made it very clear there..

Answer (score 1):

It *might* trigger multiple reflows but in practice it won't.

When CSS styles are changed in sequence, all modern browsers will optimize the process by merging all changes in one and then perform a reflow.

(this can be noticed and it might be very annoying in situations where chaining makes sense, like when adding a `no-transition` class before another... in those cases you have to rely on inconsistent hacks to force a reflow/repaint)